# java.lang.StackOverflowError when adding colomns to a dataframe with a for loop and Withcolumn fonction in spark scala

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, aws-glue

I have a spark code that add columns in a dataframe from a configuation file and finally select only the existing columns in the configuration file to create a new dataframe.

When I have less that 2000 fields on my configuration file, the script works well. However, when I add 2000 columns on the configuration file, which make it something like 4000 columns, I have a  java.lang.StackOverflowError. When debugging, I can see that the for loop and withcolumn function are the causes of  the java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Here is the line of code:

```
val configuration_file = spark.textFile("s3://fields.txt").map(cols=>cols.split(";").take(1)).flatMap(x=>x).collect().toList
var df_1 = df.toDF().cache()
for(i<- configuration_file) {
   if(!df_1.schema.fieldNames.contains(i)){
        df_1 = df_1.withColumn(i, lit(null).cast(StringType))     
     }

     }
val df_2 = df_1.select( configuration_file.head,  configuration_file.tail: _*)
```

Does anyone know how I can optimize this?
I guess the for loop is what is causing trouble.
I have a cluster with 10 workers and I have already increased the JVM memory

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss100M --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xss100M
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This code reads the file, splits the lines, and takes the first column directly in a more efficient manner

```
val configurationFile = spark.textFile("s3://configuration_fields.txt").flatMap(cols => cols.split(";").headOption).collect().toList
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have checked the logs once more, I guess the trouble is not the collect but the for loop later on, I will edit the overmetioned code. Your help is appreciated.